# Continuous functions on closed and open intervals

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

(a) If f is continuous on $[a,b]$ and $f(x) > 0$ for all $x \in [a,b]$, then there is
some constant $C > 0$ such that $f(x) \geq C$ for all $x \in [a,b]$.

(b) If f is continuous on $(a,b)$ and $f(x) > 0$ for all $x \in (a,b)$, then there is
some constant $C > 0$ such that $f(x)\geq C$ for all $x \in (a,b)$.

Are the above statements true or False? If true, prove and if false, give a counterexample.

I believe (a) is true and I think we should use the max/min theorem to prove it but I am not sure how. Could anyone help me out please? Thanks

I think (b) is false. Because if we take:

$f(x) = 1/{x^2}$. Then, f is continuous on $(0,\infty)$. But there is no $C > 0$ such that $f(x) \geq C$ for all $x \in (0,\infty)$.
Am I right?

Comment: Your argument for (b) is correct. For (a) ,use max min theorem to find $c\in [a, b]$ so that $f(x) \geq f(c)$ for all $x$. But now $f(c)>0$....

Comment: A better counterexample for (b) would perhaps be $f(x)=x$ for $x\in (0,1)$ since one might perhaps want to have a bounded interval $(a,b)$.

Comment: I am still a little confused about (a) though. I am still unsure how I could use the min/max theorem to find $c$ so that $f(x) \geq f(c)$

Answer (score 1):

By the [extreme value theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem) there's $c\in[a,b]$ such that

$$f(x)\ge f(c)>0,\quad \forall x\in [a,b]$$

Comment: Yes that's the extreme value/ min max theorem. But the question says we need to prove why it's true.

Comment: Do you need to **prove** the min/max theorem or should you **apply** it?

Comment: I guess i should apply it. The question says prove that the statement is true.

Comment: What does the min/max theorem say for a continuous function $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Suppose that f is defined and continuous on $[a,b]$ where a<b. Then, $f([a,b])$ is compact. This is the min/max theorem right?

Comment: Yes ---in a sense, but where is the min, where is the max?

Comment: There exist numbers $p$ and $q$ in $[a,b]$ such that $f(p) \geq f(x) \geq f(q)$ ?

Comment: Yes, the latter is a consequence of the min/max theorem as you stated it. After "such that" you should include a universal quantifier "for all $x\in [a,b]$". Now, since $f(x)>0$ for all $x$ by assumption, also $f(q)>0$. The $q$ now plays the role of the "$c$" in the answer by Rami.

Comment: So that would be the proof for it right?

Answer (score 0):

(a) is true. By the extreme value theorem there's some $c$ such that $f(x)\geq f(c)>0$ for all $x\in[a,b]$. Let $C=\frac{1}{2}f(c)>0$ and we are done.

(b) is false. Consider $f(x)=x$ on $(0,1)$. If $C<1$ then $f(\frac{1}{2}C)<C$ and if $C\geq 1$ then $f(\frac{1}{2})<C$, so $\forall C>0,\exists x$ such that $f(x)<C$

Answer (score 0):

Prove of (a):
Since $[a,b]$ is compact, $f(x)$ is continuous on $[a,b]$
then $f(x)$ attains a maximum and a minimum on $[a,b]$

Say $f(a)=2C$ is the minimum of $f(x)$ on $[a,b]$.
Then $f(x) > C ~~ \forall x \in [a,b]$